# Difference between these two namespaces in javascript

Tags: javascript

First off, all I'm trying to do is to structure my javascript code properly. I've been told I must not have anything global. So I took the 2 types of namespaces declaration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration) and now asking you guys for the pros and cons of each.

```
    var namespace1 = new function () {
        var internalFunction = function () {
        };

        this.publicFunction = function () {
        };
    };

    var namespace2 = {
        publicFunction: function () {
        }
    };
```

Also, how do i have a private function in the last one `namespace2`?

Comment: I am frankly surprised this question does not have an answer yet.

Comment: Where is @Felix Kling or @BoltClock or @Pointy or @alex? One of those guys. I'd like to see what you guys have to say... ;)

Comment: @Jared: Seems we were too late :D Actually I'm surprised that the first syntax (`namespace1`) works. Didn't know that you can have an "immediate constructor" this way. Always learning...

Comment: "I've been told I must not have anything global." - I think, rather, say "I must minimise my use of globals", because your namesapce object needs to be global. But certainly keeping all of your code within your own namespace is a good plan.

Comment: Felix - ECMA 262 §11.2.2 defines *NewExpression* as *new NewExpression*, §11.2 says that *NewExpression* can be *new MemberExpression* and a function expression is a *MemberExpression*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how complex your object is. For most cases, the first method is bloated and less clear. A simple object declaration is usually much cleaner:

```
var namespace = {
    f1: function () {
        // Do thing 1
    },
    f2: function () {
        // Do thing 2
    }
};
```

However, it is not possible to create private functions like this, as only functions, not object literals, create scope. Depending on your school of thought, this may not be a problem. I like to have all my methods "public", but indicate that some of them are meant for internal use by prefixing their names with an `_`. This lets you easily unit test functions intended to be "private".

At the same time, you may have meaningless temporary variables (like `i`) used to initialise the namespace, which you do want to hide by using a function.

Of course, the first method of using a function gives you more control, not only over private/public access, but over when the "namespace" is initialized. The example you used instantiates the namespace immediately with `new`, but can also choose to do this on DOM ready, or after some AJAX has completed.

Answer (score 0):

private function in namespace2.

publicFunction reveal privateFunction using Revelation Pattern.

```
var namespace2;

(function() {

    function privateFunction() {
    }

    namespace2 = {
       publicFunction : privateFunction
    };

}());

namespace2.publicFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap it in a closure, and return it with you explicit visibility.

```
namespace2 = (function(){
  function private_function() {
    //..
  }

  function publicFunction1() {
    private_function(); // accessible here
  }

  return {
    exportedPublicFunction1: publicFunction1
  };
})();

namespace2.exportedPublicFunction1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Javascript closures.  It took me a while to get them but they will allow you to have private members.  [Here's an article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) by Douglas Crockford on them that's pretty straightforward, and [another](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures) by the Mozilla folks.

I use closures and expose selected methods through namespaces.  It works pretty well and helps us keep our code tidy.